# Using JavaScript to change CSS style based on page width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on an assignment for a class where I have to make an external JavaScript file that checks a page's current width and changes the linked CSS style based on it, and have that occur whenever the page loads or is resized. Normally, we are given an example to base our assignment off of, but that was not the case this time around.

Essentially we are to use an if...then statement to change the style. I have no clue what the appropriate statements would be for the function. I've looked around and the potential solutions are either too advanced for the class or don't go over what I need. As far as I know I cannot use jQuery or CSS queries.

If someone could give me an example of how I would write this out, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: You need to give it your best shot first and post what you tried etc...

Comment: [window.onresize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize).

Comment: Are you supposed to change the CSS file itself or just replace the file?

Comment: I was given two separate external CSS documents, so I need to replace the file.

Comment: why not use Media Queries? instead of changing the link and reloading the entire CSS of all elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

html is

```
<div id="resize" style="background:red; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
```

javascript is

```
var resize = document.getElementById('resize');
window.onresize=function(){
    if(window.innerWidth <= 500) {
        resize.style = "background:blue; height: 100px; width: 100px;";
    }
    else {
        resize.style = "background:red; height: 100px; width: 100px;";
    }
};
```

i have create a sample for you look at here [TESTRESIZE](http://jsfiddle.net/kpE6w/1/)
try resizing your browser and let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's the basic idea, yes. The only difference is that the thing that is being changed is an external CSS document being applied to the HTML. I don't know how that would be different, though.

Comment: you can try this [click here!](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript)

Comment: stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
stylesheet.insertRule(".have-border { border: 1px solid black;}", 0);

Answer (score 0):

//Use This//

```
function adjustStyle() {
var width = 0;
// get the width.. more cross-browser issues
if (window.innerHeight) {
    width = window.innerWidth;
} else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
    width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
} else if (document.body) {
    width = document.body.clientWidth;
}
// now we should have it
if (width < 799) {
    document.getElementById("CSS").setAttribute("href",     "http://carrasquilla.faculty.asu.edu/GIT237/smallStyle.css");
} else {
    document.getElementById("CSS").setAttribute("href", "http://carrasquilla.faculty.asu.edu/GIT237/largeStyle.css");
}
}

// now call it when the window is resized.
window.onresize = function () {
adjustStyle();
};
window.onload = function () {
adjustStyle();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS and media queries. It's bad idea to change style by js.